# Send and save data to php with construct2

Tags: php, construct, construct-2

Im trying the past 2 weeks to send and save data to a php but with no luck.
So, my goal is , to give the ability to users have download my app from playstore to can vote if they agree or not for something in the app.
To do that i put a yes sigh and a no sign , when the user press the yes sign , a vote go to php file and save so all the users can see the results.
I make a php

```
<?php
    $postdata = $_POST['postdata'];
    $getdata = $_GET['getdata'];

    echo("postdata: ");
    if(isset($postdata)) {
        echo ($postdata .", ");
    } else {
        echo ("post data not set, ");
    }

    echo("getdata: ");
    if(isset($getdata)) {
        echo($getdata);
    } else {
        echo("get data not set");
    }
?>
```

and i send a "POST" whith AJAX on construct2 to 
URL   "https://sirmobilegames.000webhostapp.com/Vote1.php?getdata=gettest"

and the data    "postdata=" & URLEncode(ta)

"ta" is a variable in construct with value 1.

and i use METHOD:  POST

After i export this to NW.js i run it and when i press the button it says 
postdata: 1 , getdata: get data not set
if i press it once again 
postdata: 2 , getdata: get data not set
so it update the postdata but when i close the app and open it again 
im trying to read the postdata and i get 
postdata: post data not set , getdata: get data not set.

Why it cant save the variable i send it.

Comment: why would you send data using both POST and GET  at the same time ?

Comment: Its update at the same time i think so.